# performSegueWithIdentifier while in URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am checking on a test Server if a user is registered. If the server gives back, that the username and password are true, i want to perform a Segue with the identifier "Login". If I put the performeSegue inside the URLSession dataTask the program crashes with this error: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
I don't know what to do. because of the resume() function I can't put the performSegue outside of the dataTask. It would be executed before i get the data from the server.

Here is my Code:

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var session:String?

    if userName.text!.isEmpty || logInPassword.text!.isEmpty{
        let noUserName = UIAlertController(title: "Kein Benutzername oder Passwort", message: "Bitte geben sie einen Benutzernamen und ein Passwort ein.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        noUserName.addAction(OKAction)
        self.present(noUserName, animated: true)
    } else {
        //Implementing URLSession
        let urlString = "http://www.***.me/playground/api/v1/user/login/\(userName.text!)/\(logInPassword.text!)"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Error: couldn't open link")
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }

            //Implement JSON decoding and parsing
            do {
                //Decode retrived data with JSONDecoder and assing type of Article object
                let personsData = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginTest.self, from: responseData)
                session = personsData.session
                dump(personsData)

            } catch let jsonError {
                print("Error: \(jsonError)")

            }

            if session != nil{
                //loging in
                print("now loged in")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Login", sender: self)
                //here it crashes

            } else {
                let alertWrongPassword = UIAlertController(title: "Benutzername und Passwort stimmen nicht überein", message: "Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertWrongPassword.addAction(self.OKAction)
                self.present(alertWrongPassword, animated: true)
            }
        }.resume()
        //End implementing URLSession
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint. It gives you more information about the kind and reason of the exception. It seems that the crash reason is not directly related to that code. And you should put the *good* code into the `do` scope – that avoids the check `session != nil`–  and the *bad* code into the `catch` scope

Comment: Maybe this helps, it's also in the crashlog:

This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Comment: but it only crashes if I want to perform the segue there. If I put it at the beginning of the function it perfectly works fine, just without the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the exception reason you have to perform the segue on the main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Login", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: that worked, and I also put the if statment into the do catch. Thanks for the quick solution. Now I can start googleing why I need DispatchQueue.

Comment: `dataTask` is dispatched to a background thread to keep the UI responsive and all actions affecting the UI must be performed on the main thread. `DispatchQueue` handles that very conveniently.